# knockout JS $parent object change its information inside for-each loop

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout js code in magento2 order summery detail page.

here is the code

```
<p data-bind="text:console.log('parent befor', $parent)"></p> 
    <!--ko foreach: { data: JSON.parse($parent.options), as: 'option' } -->
        <p data-bind="text:console.log('parent after', $parent)"></p>
```

The $parent variable changes its content once we go inside foreach loop. I need some other information of this $parent variable once inside loop but it all get replaced by some unknown information. Here is my console.log. How i can use the original $parent information inside foreach loop.

```
parent befor {item_id: "300", name: "Vertual Product", qty: 1, price: "3.0000", base_price: "3.0000"}

parent after UiClass {_super: undefined, ignoreTmpls: {…}, _requested: {…}, containers: Array(1), exports: {…}, …}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour that you are seeing is that the context has changed, therefore, what is considered the parent has changed.  You have gone from being outside a loop to being inside a loop.

Have a look at the `$parents` array property.  You should find what you are looking for there.  Based on the description above, what you are looking for should be found in `$parents[1]`  https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Thank you @Nathan your answer realy helped. I got my value using "$parentContext.$parent" in the inner loop. <p data-bind="text:console.log('parent after', $parentContext.$parent)"></p>

Answer (score 1):

$parent inside foreach binding refers context of foreach loop and not the parent context.

Use **$parents[1]**

It will refer to the parent context.

Comment: I got my value using "$parentContext.$parent" in the inner loop